# Axios Post Request: Output saved in Config Data instead of Data field

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, mern

I'm following this [MERN Stack Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Vd5RRZXIyo&t=7810s) to build a simple app, and running into a frustrating issue.

On the front end (React side), I am making an Axios post request to store student into a student database.

```
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/students',
    data: student
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.config.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

As seen in the picture, the data is correctly stored in `response.config.data` (i.e. student with name=bob, grade=5th, section=b). However, the `response.data` property itself doesn't contain any of this info. I need this info (name=bob, grade=5th, section=b) stored in `response.data` in order for this to appear in the database.

[image]

On the backend, I have the following 3 files (controllers/student.js imported in routers/student.js which imported in index.js)

`index.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import studentRoutes from './routes/student.js';

const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3001"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

app.use('/students', studentRoutes);
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "20mb", extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "20mb", extended:true}));
app.use(cors());
```

`routes/student.js`

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors"; //Import Cors

import { getStudents, createStudent} from "../controllers/student.js"
import student from '../models/student.js';
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', getStudents); //res = response req=request
router.post('/', createStudent); 


export default router;
```

`controllers/student.js`

```
export const createStudent= async (req, res) =>{
    const student= req.body;

    const newStudent= new StudentData(student); //model(variable)

    try {
        console.log(newStudent)
        await newStudent.save();
        res.status(201).json(newStudent);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({message: error.message})
        
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to add ```response.config.data``` Json value into ```data``` variable ??

Comment: @NalinNishant essentially yes that's the idea! What is currently located in `response.config.data`, I would like to see in `response.data`

Comment: You can simply add those value by using ```(prev) => { [ response.config.data, ...data ] };```

Comment: Hmm would this go within the Axios call itself?

Comment: you could just send the response like this `const res = {response:{ data:response.config.data}} res.status(201).json(res);` something like this

Comment: What does your `StudentData` model look like?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've registered your body-parsing middleware *after* your router. The order is significant.

Because your router handles the request before the `json()` middleware has had a chance to work, `req.body` is empty.

You can also drop `body-parser` and your custom CORS middleware. These are already provided by [`express`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express) and [`cors`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) respectively.

```js
const app = express();

// Always register cors() first
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3001",
      "https://your-production-domain.example.com",
    ],
  })
);

// JSON body parser, there is no `extended` option here
app.use(express.json({ limit: "20mb" }));

// URL-encoded body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "20mb", extended: true }));

// Your router
app.use("/students", studentRoutes);
```